# I need to get minimum value in this hierarchical structure using SQL Only

Tags: sql, oracle11g

First, with one chunk of collateral, you can borrow money many times from bank. So one collateral_num can have many corresponding loan_num entries.

Second, you can use many chunks of collateral for one loan. So one loan_num can have many corresponding collateral_num entries.

There is a table like this named LOAN.

```
collateral_num | loan_num
-------------------------

 C2            |  A5
 C1            |  A5
 C3            |  A1
 C3            |  A3
 C6            |  A7
 C2            |  A1
 C7            |  A7
```

I want to get the minimum collateral_num from LOAN like this table below.

There are two groups in the first table. One of them is from first row to fifth row. We can find some relationship like  C1→a5→c2→a1→c3→a3 in the first group.

We discard the nodes including 'a'.
As a result c1 will be minimum collateral num  in c1, c2, c3 (because c1 has the least number.)

In the second group (c6→a7→c7), minimum collateral num will be c6.

I need to make an SQL query to get this result. But I have no idea how to do this.

```
collateral_num | minimum_collateral_num | loan_num
--------------------------------------------------
 C1            |   C1                   |    A5
 C2            |   C1                   |    A5
 C2            |   C1                   |    A1
 C3            |   C1                   |    A1
 C3            |   C1                   |    A3
 C6            |   C6                   |    A7
 C7            |   C6                   |    A7
```

How can I write the appropriate SQL query?

Comment: Hi @hyunjongyui what's your RDBMs ? Meaning: mysql, postgre, oracle mssql? Consider in put the proper tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a JOIN of LOAN with LOAN, specify the results to be UNIQUE, and find the lowest value of C*.

If you need more detail or hope somebody to write the exact statement for you, please at least create the model at http://www.sqlfiddle.com